# Calculations on the date of - record dates in the form of a relative

Tags: javascript

I need to develop a code that will calculate the date:

Last Sunday - last Thursday - Sunday before the last instance. (current day 10-06) 07-06, 04-06, 31-05

Last Thursday - last Sunday - the penultimate Thursday eg. (current day 05-06) 04-06, 31-05, 28-05

If the current day is Thursday: the current Thursday - last Sunday - last Thursday for example. (current day 18-06) 18-06, 14-06, 11-06

if the current day is Sunday: current Sunday - last Thursday - last Sunday for example. (current day 21-06) 21-06, 18-06, 14-06

Just sometimes bad calculates these dates shows not as it should be, as it was last 14-06, it showed the first date: 14-06, second date 14-06, date of the third 11-06 it's not good. Today shows (19-06): 14-06, 11-06, 07-06 should 18-06, 14-06, 11-06.

```
    function getLastThursday() {
  var lt = new Date();
  lt.setDate(lt.getDate() - lt.getDay()-3);
  // lt = lt.getDate();
  return lt;
}
function getLastSunday() {
  var ls = new Date();
  ls.setDate(ls.getDate() - ls.getDay());
  // ls = ls.getDate();
  return ls;
}
//penultimate Thursday
function get2LastThursday() {
  var twolt = new Date();
  twolt.setDate(twolt.getDate() - twolt.getDay()-10);
  // lt = lt.getDate();
  return twolt;
}
// penultimate Saturday
function get2LastSunday() {
  var twols = new Date();
  twols.setDate(twols.getDate() - twols.getDay()-7);
  // ls = ls.getDate();
  return twols;
}
var dLastThursday = getLastThursday().getDate();//number of the day
var dLastSunday = getLastSunday().getDate();//number of the day
var d2LastThursday = get2LastThursday().getDate();//number penultimate day
var d2LastSunday = get2LastSunday().getDate();//number penultimate day
var mLastThursday = getLastThursday().getMonth()+1; // month number
var mLastSunday = getLastSunday().getMonth()+1; // month number
var m2LastThursday = get2LastThursday().getMonth()+1; // number penultimate month
var m2LastSunday = get2LastSunday().getMonth()+1; // number penultimate month
var dForAllLastThursday = ('0' + (getLastThursday().getDate())).slice(-2);//to display from zero
var mForAllLastThursday = ('0' + (getLastThursday().getMonth()+1)).slice(-2);
var dForAllLastSunday = ('0' + (getLastSunday().getDate())).slice(-2);
var mForAllLastSunday = ('0' + (getLastSunday().getMonth()+1)).slice(-2);
var d2ForAllLastSunday = ('0' + (get2LastSunday().getDate())).slice(-2);
var m2ForAllLastSunday = ('0' + (get2LastSunday().getMonth()+1)).slice(-2);
var d2ForAllLastThursday = ('0' + (get2LastThursday().getDate())).slice(-2);
var m2ForAllLastThursday = ('0' + (get2LastThursday().getMonth()+1)).slice(-2);
var allLastThursday = dForAllLastThursday+"-"+mForAllLastThursday; // Day - month
var allLastSunday = dForAllLastSunday+"-"+mForAllLastSunday; // day - month
var all2LastThursday = d2ForAllLastThursday+"-"+m2ForAllLastThursday; // day - penultimate month
var all2LastSunday = d2ForAllLastSunday+"-"+m2ForAllLastSunday; // day - penultimate month

var roznica = dLastSunday - dLastThursday;

var d = new Date();
if(d.getDay() == 4 || d.getDay() == 0){
    var isToday = 1; // confirmation that today is Thursday or Sunday
    var dToday = d.getDate();
    var mToday = d.getMonth()+1;
    //adding a zero to the front as you need when you 1-9
    var dForAllToday = ('0' + d.getDate()).slice(-2);
    var mForAllToday = ('0' + (d.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2);
    var allToday = dForAllToday+"-"+mForAllToday;
//the problem with bad showing how the first Thursday or Sunday of the month and last Thursday or Sunday of the month to reduce the problem    
    if (roznica > 20 || roznica < -20) {
        if(dLastSday < dLastFday)
        {
            lastday = allLastSunday;
            lastday2 = allLastThursday;
        }
        else
        {
            lastday = allLastThursday;
            lastday2 = allLastSunday;
        }
    }else if(dLastSunday > dLastThursday){
        lastday = allLastSunday;
         lastday2 = allLastThursday;
    }else{
        lastday = allLastThursday;
        lastday2 = allLastSunday;
    }
}
//the problem with bad showing how the first Thursday or Sunday of the month and last Thursday or Sunday of the month to reduce the problem
else if (roznica > 20 || roznica < -20)
{
    if(dLastSunday < dLastThursday)
    {
        lastday = allLastSunday;
        lastday2 = allLastThursday;
        lastday3 = all2LastSunday;
    }
    else{
        lastday = allLastThursday;
        lastday2 = allLastSunday;
        lastday3 = all2LastThursday;
    }
}
else if(dLastSunday > dLastThursday)
{
    lastday = allLastSunday;
    lastday2 = allLastThursday;
    lastday3 = all2LastSunday;

}
else
{
    lastday = allLastThursday;
    lastday2 = allLastSunday;
    lastday3 = all2LastThursday;
}
if (typeof allToday != 'undefined') {
    firstDay = allToday;
    secondDay = lastday;
    thridDay = lastday2;
} else{
    firstDay = lastday;
    secondDay = lastday2;
    thridDay = lastday3;
}
console.log(allLastSunday);
console.log(allLastThursday);
console.log(getLastSunday());
console.log(getLastThursday());
var piecesFirst = firstDay.split("-");
var firstCharPiecesFirst = piecesFirst[0].charAt(0);
var firstCharPiecesFirst2 = piecesFirst[1].charAt(0);
if (firstCharPiecesFirst=="0") {piecesFirst[0] = piecesFirst[0].charAt(1);};
if (firstCharPiecesFirst2=="0") {piecesFirst[1] = piecesFirst[1].charAt(1);};
var piecesSecond = secondDay.split("-");
var firstCharPiecesSecond = piecesSecond[0].charAt(0);
var firstCharPiecesSecond2 = piecesSecond[1].charAt(0);
if (firstCharPiecesSecond=="0") {piecesSecond[0] = piecesSecond[0].charAt(1);};
if (firstCharPiecesSecond2=="0") {piecesSecond[1] = piecesSecond[1].charAt(1);};
var piecesThrid = thridDay.split("-");
var firstCharPiecesThrid = piecesThrid[0].charAt(0);
var firstCharPiecesThrid2 = piecesThrid[1].charAt(0);
if (firstCharPiecesThrid=="0") {piecesThrid[0] = piecesThrid[0].charAt(1);};
if (firstCharPiecesThrid2=="0") {piecesThrid[1] = piecesThrid[1].charAt(1);};
```

Comment: What exactly does it do when it "breaks down"? Give specifics, or you won't get much help here.

Comment: You might want to look into a library like moment.js instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I know in function getLastThursday(), get2LastThursday(), get2LastSunday() problem but i don't know how get last thursday, 2LastThursday, 2LastSunday

Answer (score 0):

I use getTime() for date calculations and just add/subtract miliseconds.
This has the extra advantage that you automatically handle things like leap years and makes it easier to check for things like DST.

Comment: Daylight savings time.